# Can a US citizen living abroad open a US bank account?

Tags: united-states, canada, bank-account

I am both a citizen of Canada and a citizen of the US (dual citizenship) but I am living in Canada at the moment. I have a US passport and a Social Security Number. Can I open up a bank account in a US bank without living in the US? If so, how might I go about doing this?

Also, I would like to avoid visiting the US to do this if that is at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can open a bank account.  I looked at the sites of several major banks, including Chase, Bank of America, and TD Bank, and all of them have services for U.S. citizens living abroad to hold a U.S. bank account.  The common theme seems to be that you have a social security number, which is a requisite, and your credit history may also be a factor in their decision to open an account, but evidently your circumstance is not that uncommon.